# canvas fill text vanishes when hovering over chartjs pie chart

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js

I am using a doughnut chart from chartjs, and in the center of this canvas I am filling two lines of text. These show up fine after the initial animation, but when I hover over the doughnut, a tool tip shows up for the relevant element (which is expected), but the fill text vanishes. Any reason why this might be happening and how I can rectify it ?

here is the code I am using to generate the text on the canvas

```
var pieChart = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(pieChart).Doughnut(pieData, {percentageInnerCutout : 80, animationEasing: "easeOutQuart", onAnimationComplete: function() {
        pieChart.fillStyle = 'black'
        pieChart.font = "50px Roboto";
        pieChart.textAlign = "center";
        pieChart.fillText(distributionChartData[3]+" %", 135, 120);
        pieChart.font = "20px Roboto";
        pieChart.fillText((distributionChartData[0]+distributionChartData[1]+distributionChartData[2])+" Responses", 135, 160);
    }
});
```

Here is an image of the chart after initial load[image]

this is the image after hover[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can do this with a simple extension of the chart type you are using and moving your draw code to inside the draw override

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**Code**

```
Chart.types.Doughnut.extend({
    name: "DoughnutAlt",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Doughnut.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        this.chart.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
        this.chart.ctx.font = "50px Roboto";
        this.chart.ctx.textAlign = "center";
        this.chart.ctx.fillText(distributionChartData[3] + " %", 135, 120);
        this.chart.ctx.font = "20px Roboto";
        this.chart.ctx.fillText((distributionChartData[0] + distributionChartData[1] + distributionChartData[2]) + " Responses", 135, 160);
    }
});

var pieChart = document.getElementById("pieChart").getContext("2d");
new Chart(pieChart).DoughnutAlt(pieData, {
    percentageInnerCutout: 80, animationEasing: "easeOutQuart"
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/p979zyLj/

Comment: `.extend` looks like a good way to inherit the Chart and run code after the base `.draw` has completed. Upvote for a good solution and for giving me new info--I enjoy learning! :-)

Comment: @markE - me too, and the new chartjs looks to be even better!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is going on in this code? I am having the same problem with a bar chart, but I don't understand exactly what the fix is here.

Comment: @dchadney - you override the draw method to first call the original draw and then write the text in the middle. it was originally disappearing because OP didn't have a write text after every draw (only after the _first_ animation complete)

Answer (score 2):

ChartJS will redraw itself as needed (for example when displaying tooltips), so you must redraw your "% and responses" text whenever ChartJS refreshes (redraws) the chart.

<strike>You can set ChartJS's '[onAnimationComplete](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration)' callback to draw your call your "% and responses" text when ChartJs has completed it's own drawing and animating.</strike>

**[ Addition: ]**

I've taken a look at the ChartJS source code and the Issues on Github.

There is currently no way within the ChartJS API to trigger redraws of your custom text (your "% and responses") after a tooltip closes.

One workaround would be to use CSS to place a div with your "% and responses" over the chart.

Comment: thanks. I might be mistaken but if you refer the code I have included in my question, I think I am actually doing my fill text within the 'onAnimationComplete' callback. Am I mistaken ? Sorry if I am, I am very new to js development.

Comment: @vsank7787. Yep, my bad. :-z  You are indeed using the onAnimationComplete (I should have scrolled your question code to see that).

Comment: @vsank7787, I've updated my answer to (sadly) report that there is currently no way to redraw custom labels following the display of a tooltip.

Comment: thank you for the extensive research, I might use the CSS with div method. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually you can do this by a simple extension (which Chart.js supports) - have added an answer for this. I guess you could also do this by using a customTooltips in addition to onAnimationComplete (but the former seemed cleaner)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set `option: {animation: false}` on your Chartjs settings to solve this.