# Chart.JS - Fill Donut

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm working on an app. This app displays some Donut charts using Chart.js. I'm trying to fill the donut "hole" with yellow. Within the donut hole, I want to place an image. However, I've been unsuccessful in my attempts. Currently, I have the following, which can be seen in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00wrg5nw/1/).

```
var data = [{
    value: 30,
    color: "#F7464A"
}, {
    value: 50,
    color: "#E2EAE9"
}, {
    value: 100,
    color: "#D4CCC5"
}, {
    value: 40,
    color: "#949FB1"
}, {
    value: 120,
    color: "#4D5360"
}

]

var options = {
    animation: false,
    backgroundColor: [
        'yellow'
    ]
};

//Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var c = $('#myChart');
var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
/*************************************************************************/
myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Doughnut(data, options);
```

How do you customize the donut fill? Thanks!

Comment: does http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-patterns help? could fiddle it out for ya but this seems to do what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after `options`:

```
Chart.types.Doughnut.extend({
    name: "DoughnutAlt",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Doughnut.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

          //find the center point
          var x = this.chart.canvas.clientWidth / 2;
          var y = this.chart.canvas.clientHeight / 2;

          //render the text
          this.chart.ctx.beginPath();
          this.chart.ctx.arc(x,y,100,0,2*Math.PI);
          this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = '#ffff00';
          this.chart.ctx.fill();
    }
});
```

Change `myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Doughnut(data, options);` to `myNewChart = new Chart(ct).DoughnutAlt(data, options);`

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00wrg5nw/4/)

Refer to this answer: [canvas fill text vanishes when hovering over chartjs pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620215/canvas-fill-text-vanishes-when-hovering-over-chartjs-pie-chart)

**UPDATE**:

Add background image:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'path_to_image_source';

this.chart.ctx.drawImage(img,135,130);
```

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00wrg5nw/6/) showing image inside donut chart

Comment: Looks good at first but the background color goes away as soon as you mouse over the chart's arcs.

Comment: Updated my answer. I also added a link to another question to which you can also refer to.